# What is an efficient way of transforming and counting an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects that I want to count and transform.  For instance:

```
[#<User id:1, count:0>, #<User id:2, count:0>, #<User id:2, count:0>, #<User id:3, count:0>, #<User id:1, count:0>, #<User id:1, count:0>]
```

would become:

```
[#<User id:1, count:3>, #<User id:2, count:2>, #<User id:3, count:1>]
```

The transformation is what confuses me, since a 'map', goes straight through, but this would be recursive.

Comment: Are the input counts always 0? If not, do you want the sum of all of them?

Comment: The input counts may not be zero.. and I don't need the sum of them, so the answers provided should be fine.  Thanks for asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[user1, user2, user2, user3, user1, user1].group_by(&:id).map do |id, users|
  users.first.count = users.size
  users.first
end
```

Comment: Nice. But each makes more sense than map since it's just transforming.

Comment: @pguardiario it returns the 3-element array OP's asking for

Comment: Hmm, he asked to count and transform the array, not return a new one.

Comment: Thank you, this got the job done, very well! On another note, is there a reason my question got down voted?  Maybe I should avoid asking questions like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[user1, user2, user2, user3, user1, user1] \
  .group_by(&lambda{|x| x}) \
  .map{ |k, v| k.count = v.count; k }
```

Comment: Just as a FYI, in Ruby 1.9.2+ you don't need the continuation `'\'` characters. 1.8.7 needs them still.